# How to get the number of characters in a file (not bytes) in C on Linux

Tags: c, linux, unicode, encoding

I would like to get the number of characters in a file. By characters I mean "real" characters, not bytes. Assuming I know the file encoding.

I tried to use `mbstowcs()` but it doesn't work because it uses the system locale (or the one defined with setlocale). Because setlocale is not thread-safe, I don't think it's a good idea to use it before calling `mbstowcs()`. Even if it was tread-safe, I would have to be sure that
my program won't "jump" (signal, etc) between the calls of `setlocale()` (one call to set it to the encoding of the file, and on call to revert to the previous one).

So, to take an example, imagine we have a file *ru.txt* encoded using a russian encoding (KOI8 for example). So, I would like to open the file and get the numbers of characters, assuming the encoding of the file is KOI8.

It could be so easy if `mbstowcs()` could take a `source_encoding` argument...

EDIT: An other problem using `mbstowcs()` is that the locale corresponding to the encoding of the file has to be installed on the system...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd suggest using iconv(3):

```
NAME
   iconv - perform character set conversion

SYNOPSIS
   #include <iconv.h>

   size_t iconv(iconv_t cd,
                char **inbuf, size_t *inbytesleft,
                char **outbuf, size_t *outbytesleft);
```

and convert to utf32. You get 4 byte output for every character converted (plus 2 for the BOM). It should be possible to convert the input piece by piece using a fix size outbuf, if one choses outbytesleft carefully (i.e. 4 * inbytesleft + 2 :-).

Comment: I think you can get rid of the BOM by choosing an output encoding with a defined byte order, e.g. "UTF-32BE".

Comment: 'get rid of the BOM by choosing an output encoding with a defined bytes order, e.g. "UTF-32BE"'. => Yes, you're right, this is indeed the case, at least with iconv(1) the programm.

Comment: This should work, but I won't be able to use any of the string manipulation functions on outbuf : strlen, etc. I would have to write a utf32_strlen() function which divide the strlen() / 4 and substract 2. Is there a better way ?

Comment: @ThibautD.: `iconv()` returns the number of converted characters, so there is no need to determine the length of the converted string.

Comment: I do not understand why this valid answer is downvoted (without any explaining comments)!

Comment: It's not my downvote. I understand that your answer solve this specific problem, but if the result is not a wchar_t*, I won't be able to use builtin functions on it to search/etc in the string. It's like a fix to a special case, not a generic solution.

Comment: @ThibautD.: The output of `iconv --list` on my Linux system shows that "WCHAR_T" is also a supported output encoding. - Btw. your question was only about *counting* the number of characters, so I would not consider this answer as "fix to a special case", but as a solution to exactly your problem.

Comment: I found a example with WCHAR_T convertion as you said : http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/iconv-Examples.html It seems very good. You can use `wcstrlen()` on the result and call `iconv()` again to transform it from wchar_t* to char*. This seems to be more "generic", I like it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the number of UTF8 characters in a file just pass it's content to this function:

```
int CalcUTF8Chars( const std::string& S )
{
    int Count = 0;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i != S.length(); i++ )
    {
        if ( ( S[i] & 0xC0 ) != 0x80 ) { Count++; }
    }

    return Count;
}
```

No external dependencies.

**Update:**

In case you want to handle other different encodings you have two choices:

1. Use a third-party library that can handle it, for example, ICU http://site.icu-project.org/
2. Write the calculation functions yourself for every encoding you want to use.

Comment: In my example, my file is not encoded in utf-8. I'm looking for a portable way to this, not writing a function for every encoding.

Comment: What is the encoding of your file? Your question is tagged UNICODE.

Comment: It could be any encoding. That's a generic question. I just assume we know the encoding.

Comment: The question (as I understand it) was about counting the number of characters in a *specified encoding* in a file, not about counting UTF-8 characters.

Comment: But your question is tagged ``unicode`` and you mention UTF8 on Linux.